# Need help blending my own animation with a mixamo animation

Tags: animation, nla-editor, mixamo

I have blended animations in the NLA editor before, but that was mixing two mixamo animations. Now I am blending my own animation with a mixamo animation.

But when my animation blends to the new one, it doesn't blend to the mixamo animation, it just blends to a t-pose.

At first i thought I changed how I blended the animations, but then I tested it by blending two mixamo animations and that worked perfectly.

The rig that I animated on my own is also a mixamo rig so thats not where the problem is. I found nothing online about this so i'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!